# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. But names and number of supplied values are correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following problem. I have a stored procedure which  looks like the following:

```
truncate table  snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware
insert into snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware
select  IdentifyingKey,
        MachineID,
        Computername,
        FQDN,
        GETDATE(),
        GETDATE(),
        '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000',
        eDirGlobalID as GlobalID,
        PrimaryUser as PrimaryUsername,
        getDate(),
        cInstallDate as InstallDate
from exampleDB.ext.exampleView
```

Im trying to insert the above listed values in the following table:

[image]

When i try to execute the stored procedure i always get the error message

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Daily, Line 63 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I have no idea where the problem is. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: new stored procedure looks like this. still getting the same error.

```
    --Machine Registered Software
truncate table  snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware
insert into snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware (
    IdentifyingKey,
    MachineID,
    Computername,
    FQDN,
    GlobalID,
    LastScanDate,
    EffectiveStartDate,
    EffectiveEndDate,
    PrimaryUsername,
    CreatedOn,
    InstallDate
)
select  IdentifyingKey = IdentifyingKey,
        MachineID = MachineID,
        Computername = Computername,
        FQDN = FQDN,
        GlobalID = eDirGlobalID,
        LastScanDate = GETDATE(),
        EffectiveStartDate = GETDATE(),
        EffectiveEndDate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000',
        PrimaryUsername = PrimaryUser,
        CreatedOn = getdate(),
        InstallDate = cInstallDate
from exampleDB.ext.exampleView
```

EDIT2: I also do not have an Identity Column in the table. Also no triggers linked to the table.

Comment: I think the order of columns is causing the issue. May be `GlobalID` should be placed immediately after `FQDN`. Either you've to give column names for each value, or follow the order of columns in table

Comment: You are trying to insert 11 fields on the target table. It seems that this table has fewer or more than 11 fields

Comment: `eDirGlobalID as GlobalID,`  has to be after  `FQDN` as it is in the table definition.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I reordered the values and put GlobalID right after FQDN, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO, calgara12. I think EzLo is onto something with the thought that the issue lays elsewhere in the procedure. If you could post the full text of the stored procedure it may help. You should be able to have SSMS generate the script for you by right clicking on the proc and selecting "Script <object> as", then "CREATE to", then "New Query Editor Window."

Answer (score 0):

Always write explicit columns on each insert:

```
insert into snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware (
    IdentifyingKey,
    MachineID,
    Computername,
    FWDN,
    GlobalID,
    LastScanDate,
    EffectiveStartDate,
    EffectiveEndDate,
    PrimaryUsername,
    CreatedOn,
    InstallDate)
select  
    IdentifyingKey,
    MachineID,
    Computername,
    FQDN,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000',
    eDirGlobalID as GlobalID,
    PrimaryUser as PrimaryUsername,
    getDate(),
    cInstallDate as InstallDate
from 
    exampleDB.ext.exampleView
```

I also recommend forcing the alias of the `SELECT` to the same order.

```
insert into snap.MachineRegisteredSoftware (
    IdentifyingKey,
    MachineID,
    Computername,
    FQDN,
    GlobalID,
    LastScanDate,
    EffectiveStartDate,
    EffectiveEndDate,
    PrimaryUsername,
    CreatedOn,
    InstallDate)
select  
    IdentifyingKey = IdentifyingKey,
    MachineID = MachineID,
    Computername = Computername,
    FQDN = FQDN,
    GlobalID = GETDATE(),
    LastScanDate = GETDATE(),
    EffectiveStartDate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000',
    EffectiveEndDate = eDirGlobalID, --as GlobalID
    PrimaryUsername = PrimaryUser, --as PrimaryUsername
    CreatedOn = getDate(),
    InstallDate = cInstallDate --as InstallDate
from 
    exampleDB.ext.exampleView
```

You can clearly see the problem is on `EffectiveEndDate` here (and probably other columns too).

You might also have an `IDENTITY` column which doesn't need to be specified and needs to be removed from the list, or columns with `DEFAULT` constraints that you either want to omit or write explicitly the `DEFAULT` keyword.

Also make sure that the problem isn't in a trigger that's linked to the table you are inserting the data into.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your suggestion, but i still get the same error. I edited my original post with the new stored procedure.

How do i check if a have an identity column? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @calgara12 check if you have triggers linked to the table you are inserting into. The message might come from the trigger. If it were an identity problem, another message would be displayed saying that you can't insert an explicit value on an indentity column without setting `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`.

Comment: ok, but there are no triggers linked to my table. Any other idea?

Also if I remove the three values LastScanDate, EffectiveStartDate and EffectiveEndDate from the table and the stored procedure it seems to work. Problem is, i need those three values.

Comment: @calgara12 you might have another parsing error on the previous or following statements. Try executing the query outside of the procedure to make sure that it's this statement thats causing the error. You can add a `WHERE` clause with `1 = 0` so it doesn't insert any rows.

Comment: If I execute the statement outside of the stored procedure it works. I don't get what the problem is. Btw im new to SQL and i really appreciate you helping me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @calgara12 what you posted isn't the complete SP. Add `;` before and after the insert and you will see that there is another problem with another statement from your SP. Include the complete `ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE` statement on your post to debug the issue.